# how can I subtract in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this is my dataframe

```
    date        number  name       di   t

0   2008-01-01  150 서울역(150)    승차  379

1   2008-01-01  150 서울역(150)    하차  145

2   2008-01-01  151 시청(151)      승차 131

3   2008-01-01  151 시청(151)      하차 35

4   2008-01-01  152 종각(152)      승차 1287

5   2008-01-01  152 종각(152)      하차 74

6   2008-01-01  153 종로3가(153)   승차  484

7   2008-01-01  153 종로3가(153)   하차  28

8   2008-01-01  154 종로5가(154)   승차  89

9   2008-01-01  154 종로5가(154)   하차  14

10  2008-01-01  155 동대문(155)    승차  190

11  2008-01-01  155 동대문(155)    하차  23

12  2008-01-01  156 신설동(156)    승차  65

13  2008-01-01  156 신설동(156)    하차  15

14  2008-01-01  157 제기동(157)    승차  156

15  2008-01-01  157 제기동(157)    하차  16
```

and

I want the result like this subtraction di(승차 - 하차)

```
    date       number   name         di     t

0   2008-01-01  150 서울역(150)    승차    234

2   2008-01-01  151 시청(151)     승차    96

4   2008-01-01  152 종각(152)     승차    1213

6   2008-01-01  153 종로3가(153)   승차  456

8   2008-01-01  154 종로5가(154)   승차  75

10  2008-01-01  155 동대문(155)    승차  167

12  2008-01-01  156 신설동(156)    승차  50

14  2008-01-01  157 제기동(157)    승차  140
```

how can i get this dataframe?

I did a google search of "dataframe subtraction" but it’s not showing the result I want, what is wrong with my search?

Comment: What does "subtraction" mean in this sense? I doesn't look like you are "subtracting" numbers (or maybe you are but it is difficult to tell)... so what is happening? Is it a coincidence that only even numbered rows are retained? Please clearly explain what "subtraction di(승차 - 하차)" is supposed to mean. Thanks.

Comment: easyly column in t 0 - 1 and 2 - 3 and 4 - 5 ( 379-145, 131-35, 1287-74) .....

Comment: Is it always going to be pairs of rows being subtracted? What if there is an odd number of rows?

Answer (score 2):

We can do the following:

1. Groupby on number and get the `diff` of each group
2. Merge back to our original dataframe based on index
3. Remove unwanted columns

```
group = abs(df.groupby('number')['t'].diff().dropna())
group.index = group.index-1

df_merge = df.merge(group, 
                    left_index=True, 
                    right_index=True, 
                    suffixes=['_1', ''])

df_merge.drop('t_1', axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df_merge)
          date  number         name    di       t
0   2008-01-01     150   서울역(150)  승차   234.0
2   2008-01-01     151     시청(151)  승차    96.0
4   2008-01-01     152     종각(152)  승차  1213.0
6   2008-01-01     153  종로3가(153)  승차   456.0
8   2008-01-01     154  종로5가(154)  승차    75.0
10  2008-01-01     155   동대문(155)  승차   167.0
12  2008-01-01     156   신설동(156)  승차    50.0
14  2008-01-01     157   제기동(157)  승차   140.0
```

Comment: Just need change a little bit about your di columns , I think he need 1st value as output, BTW nice solution

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, didnt notice, fixed. @Wen-Ben.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC get `first` under `groupby` then assign the `diff` with `dropna`

```
g=df.groupby(['date','number','name'])
yourdf=g.di.first().reset_index()
yourdf['t']=-g.t.diff().dropna().values
yourdf
Out[648]: 
         date  number       name  di       t
0  2008-01-01     150   서울역(150)  승차   234.0
1  2008-01-01     151    시청(151)  승차    96.0
2  2008-01-01     152    종각(152)  승차  1213.0
3  2008-01-01     153  종로3가(153)  승차   456.0
4  2008-01-01     154  종로5가(154)  승차    75.0
5  2008-01-01     155   동대문(155)  승차   167.0
6  2008-01-01     156   신설동(156)  승차    50.0
7  2008-01-01     157   제기동(157)  승차   140.0
```

---

Push into one line

```
df.groupby(['date','number','name']).\
     agg({'di':'first','t':lambda x : x.iloc[0]-x.iloc[1]}).reset_index()
Out[665]: 
         date  number       name  di     t
0  2008-01-01     150   서울역(150)  승차   234
1  2008-01-01     151    시청(151)  승차    96
2  2008-01-01     152    종각(152)  승차  1213
3  2008-01-01     153  종로3가(153)  승차   456
4  2008-01-01     154  종로5가(154)  승차    75
5  2008-01-01     155   동대문(155)  승차   167
6  2008-01-01     156   신설동(156)  승차    50
7  2008-01-01     157   제기동(157)  승차   140
```

Comment: first version is Length of values does not match length of index

second version is not work...

Answer (score 0):

If the rows are always paired and ordered as shown in your sample, then just do the simple math, and then `drop_duplicated()`. the calculation on the rows with an odd number index has no influence on the result (they will all be discarded).

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2['t'] = df2.t - df2.t.shift(-1)
df2.drop_duplicates(['date','number','name'])
df2
#         date  number  name    di  t
#0  2008-01-01  150 서울역(150)    승차  234.0
#2  2008-01-01  151 시청(151) 승차  96.0
#4  2008-01-01  152 종각(152) 승차  1213.0
#6  2008-01-01  153 종로3가(153)   승차  456.0
#8  2008-01-01  154 종로5가(154)   승차  75.0
#10 2008-01-01  155 동대문(155)    승차  167.0
#12 2008-01-01  156 신설동(156)    승차  50.0
#14 2008-01-01  157 제기동(157)    승차  140.0
```

**Update:** Just a follow-up to this old question. The one I suggested above had one issue for those groups with only one row (i.e. no paired row), but this can be overcome by using another `drop_duplicated()`:

```
# define columns to group rows
uniq_cols = ['date', 'number', 'name']

# find all groups/rows which do NOT have any paired rows
# and save them in a separate dataframe
# Here you can setup their value to NULL if needed
u = df.drop_duplicates(uniq_cols, keep=False)

# calculate the difference
df['t'] = df.t - df.t.shift(-1)

# concat the two data-frames and then drop_duplicated
# make sure `u` is before `df`, so that its values will be kept
# while the ones in `df` will be discarded
# sort_index() to get back to its original order.
pd.concat([u, df]).drop_duplicates(uniq_cols).sort_index()
```

**Note:** Rows need to be sorted so that rows in the same group are line-up consecutively.